# htaccess redirect with variable query params

Tags: apache, .htaccess

could you help me get this working please.

I am trying to redirect

```
/search.php?id=5GHU&distance=50&sort=title
```

or

```
/search.php?id=5GHU
```

or

```
/search.php?id=5GHU&distance=50
```

to

```
/search/?query_string_values
```

i.e. whether it's one query string parameter or many they all should go there

This is what I tried.

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)id=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^search\.php$ /search/%1? [L,R=permanent]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for my confusion about your question, I got it now.  So...

Modify your .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule "^/search.php$"    "/search/"    [L,R=301,QSA]
```

In short it will take the query string (what follows /search.php that starts with `?`) and append it to "/search/".  That is done by the QSA flag to RewriteRule.  No matter how many parameters you have, it will append it all.

See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa

So

```
/search.php?a=1&b=2  -->    /search/?a=1&b=2
/search.php?c=3      -->    /search/?c=3
```

Since `/search/?a=1&b=2` does not specify a page to use, it will use the default page defined by DirectoryIndex in your configuration.  I prefer to explicitly specify the page, but it works without.

Comment: Thanks - let me check.